# how can I mirror desktop AND audio with chromecast? (xubuntu 16.04)

Tags: sound, video, pulseaudio, streaming, chromecast

I have a google chromecast device connected to my tv, and xubuntu 16.04 fresh installed on my Toshiba portege z930-169.

I installed google chrome.

I can mirror a tab of chrome or chose to mirror the whole desktop (by clicking on a button of chrome)

If I choose to mirror the whole desktop a message appear saying that my device cannot stream audio. After a web search I see that I can use pulseaudio-dlna to stream audio.

This work but I have the following behavior:

If I stream audio, the desktop stops streaming. If I stream the desktop then tha audio stops.

Is there a way to stream BOTH desktop AND audio at once?

Comment: I have same problem. How can I do it?